# Method for measuring distance of a irregular curved profile

Tags: computational-mathematics, computational-geometry, computational-algebra, experimental-mathematics

I am trying to measure a curved profile of a surface(2D) to determine the surface availability at different rate of testing. I have attached an image for a rough picture.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2SlJ.jpg)

Actually I have a reference geometry and performed two tests to determine the behavior. They two had different profiles at top portion. So I considered an axis for reference geometry and drew radial lines with 15deg angle difference each and marked those points as 1 (15 deg anticlockwise from vertical axis),2(30 deg anticlockwise from vertical axis),3,... and measured length of the radial lines which gives the distance of the top profile at different points(L1 at pt1, L2 at pt2...). I did the same on my first test results and got the lengths L1',L2'...and with second test lengths L1",L2".... Now I estimated the deviation of the profile by calculating the error like this

test1: Error = ((L1-L1')/L1)*100%
test2: Error = ((L1-L1")/L1)*100%

As the number of experiments increases it is a bit tedious to divide lines based on angles and measure the deviation of the top profile and hence would like to look for an alternative. One approach would be to eliminate the axis and split the complete area with square grids and get the coordinates (x,y) and find the error, but this seems not too good.
Could any one please suggest an easy method to do find out the difference in the top profile?
Thanks in advance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3buw.jpg)

Comment: The method needs to take into account what kind of differences in the profile you are expecting/trying to measure. In particular, why radial lines are better than parallel lines? Is there some specific reference point for this shape? In fact, if you were to move your object closer to the intersection of your lines, you could get wildly different results than with current position. For example, how did you picked that point for the two other shapes (which are different, so there is no obvious location)?

Comment: Hi, the differences I am looking for is to know the coverage of the surface in top, that is, how far or how accurately the top profile of my experiment matches the reference. My main motto is to make some parameters change such that the profile looks as close to that of the reference. The axis I defined is based on the location where it is fixed. So the axis will lie at same location for all the tests and reference. I really don't know if radial lines are better than the parallel lines honestly, as it was my initial guess.It is not necessary that I should take the axis into consideration